# Build array from nested array

Tags: javascript

i have an array like this :

```
const toto = [{ id: 1, arrays: [{ id: 1, name: 'tatat' }, { id: 2, name: 'tutu' }] };
```

And i'd like to get :

```
[{ id: 1, arrays: [{ id: 1, name: 'tatat' }] }, { id: 1, arrays: [{ id: 2, name: 'tutu' }] }];
```

This is what i did :

```
const aEvt = [];
this.organization.events.forEach(x => {
  const e = Object.assign({}, x);
  if (x.eventToOrganizators.length > 1) {
    x.eventToOrganizators.forEach(y => {
      console.log('y', y);
      e.eventToOrganizators = [y];
      console.log('e', e.eventToOrganizators[0]); // OK get the good value
      aEvt.push(e);
    });
  } else {
    aEvt.push(e);
  }
});
console.log(aEvt); // NOT OK, e.eventToOrganizators[0] has all the time the same value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) for the outer and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for the nested array.

```js
const 
    data = [{ id: 1, arrays: [{ id: 1, name: 'tatat' }, { id: 2, name: 'tutu' }] }],
    result = data.flatMap(({ arrays, ...o }) =>
        arrays.map(item => ({ ...o, arrays: [item] }))
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Works like a charm, but didn't understand why my ugly solutions didn't works.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
const toto = [{
  id: 1,
  arrays: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'tatat'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'tutu'
  }]
}];

const result = toto.reduce((a, c) => {
  const elements = c.arrays.map(e => ({
    ...c,
    arrays: [e]
  }));
  return [...a, ...elements];
}, []);

console.log(result);
```